# dojo drag and drop

Tags: javascript, dojo

hey , i have a problem i want to make a drag and drop between 2 containers and then select the dropped item values , what is the best tutorial for that i need it in dojo framework can any one help me ?? please

Comment: Google "dojo drag and drop tutorial"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was searching info about DnD in dojo I found this blog post really helpful.

Check it out:
[Dojo DnD Tutorial - part 1](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/10/dojo-drag-and-drop-1/)

Hope it helps you as well!

Cheers,

//Daniel

Answer (score 2):

For reference,

- comprehensive explanation of dojo/dnd, and how to leverage it in real applications. The author builds the “shopping cart” in several iterations commenting code snippets and providing full source code for all examples. : [Drag and drop with Dojo](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/05/dojo-drag-n-drop-redux/)
- online demo (declarative): [Dojo Drag and Drop declarative demo](http://sitepen.github.io/sp-dnd-demo/2-dnd.markup.html)
- online demo (programmatic): [Dojo Drag and Drop programmatic demo](http://sitepen.github.io/sp-dnd-demo/2-dnd.html)

Comment: Both sources return a `404`